# regex to modify the string

Tags: java, regex

I have one string like below

```
A:82% X 18% Y B:100% X C:82% X 18% Y AB:82% X 18% Y
```

Want to convert above string into below format (Required Format)

```
#A:82% X,18% Y #B:100% X #C:82% X,18% Y #AB:82% X,18% Y
```

I'm able to achieve this

```
#A:82% X 18% Y #B:100% X #C:82% X 18% Y #AB:82% X 18% Y
```

using this code

```
String inp = "A:82% X 18% Y B:100% X C:82% X 18% Y AB:82% X 18% Y";
String regex = "(\\b[A-Za-z]{1,}\\:\\b)";   
System.out.println(inp.replaceAll(regex, "#$1"));
```

But am not able to find a way where I could place commas the way I want mentioned in required format.

Is there any way I could select only words except "#word:", "Number%" and "spaces", 
so that in resultant I could select only Xs and Ys (X and Y is just an example, other word are also possible). Because once am able to select those words then
I can replace them with "$1,"

Thanks

Comment: is the number of  (Number% Word) always fixed to 2 ?

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul, No..!

Comment: ok, see last update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: updated after comment [regex](https://regex101.com/r/HXFdMD/3)

```
(\d+%\s[A-Z]+)\s(?=\d+%\s[A-Z]+)
```

will match pattern (Number% Word) followed by (Number% Word), without consuming the second as it is a lookahead.

```
\1,
```

Java code:

```
String inp = "A:82% X 18% Y B:100% X C:82% X 18% Y AB:60% X 20% Y 20% ZZ";
String regex = "(\\b[A-Za-z]{1,}\\:\\b)";
String inp2 = inp.replaceAll(regex, "#$1");
String regex2 = "(\\d+%\\s[A-Z]+)\\s(?=\\d+%\\s[A-Z]+)";
System.out.println(inp2.replaceAll(regex2, "$1,"));
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ZY2xboMwEIZ3nuLkBskogLCHKqKKKtK5U5eWmMEBC5E6xsJO1Bbx7NROU0VpF5/vv7vv2/MTT3ot1L55n/VxJ7saasmNgWfeKRiDS2Yst66c@q6Bg5tgeLFDp9ptBXxoDUQwzsFPBJ3SsAZU5CsawiuQVQhvsMlJlvn26SYuNvn9OaaZb/1blujhFzWIVnx4GGZsty2Skidf1UjiibHcJdF100mpW3QlHYSWvBaFlPh8HwO6WxAU3VLpBdssQ8aMZ1fLyP3w4/pP6CWfxopD2h9tqh3CSoW98J@KOteCxChysnkKpvkb)

Comment: this answer seems great

Comment: @Nahuel, But if I use this string "A:82% X 18% Y B:100% X C:82% X 18% Y AB:60% X 20% Y 20% ZZ", I'm not able to get comma before "20% ZZ".

Comment: @Squeez, i let the old answer at the end, but i will remove to make more clear

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul, Its working now...! Can you please explain little more your second regex...?

Comment: lookahead `(?=` .. `)` is a zero width assertion which ensures that pattern matches at current position without moving forward position in input.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the part between X and Y (if there is one) `[^X]*% Y`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always have input in the form `#word:number% label number% label ...` you could try the following regex to match the spaces between labels and numbers: `(?!<:)\s+(?=\d+%)`

Short breakdown:

- `(?!<:)` is a negative lookbehing meaning the match must not be preceded by a colon
- `\s+` is a sequence of one or more spaces which you want to match
- `(?=\d+%)` is a positive lookahead meaning the match must be followed by `number%`

In your test input that would match the space after each `X`.

Answer (score 0):

```
([a-zA-Z]+:)([0-9]{1,3}%) ([a-zA-Z]+)(?: ([0-9]{1,3}%) ([a-zA-Z]+))?
```

With substitution:

```
#$1 $2 $3, $4 $5
```

You would need to have an if statement to make sure capture group 4 has captured something. If it hasn't, then use substitution:

```
#$1 $2 $3
```

See the [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/whIcV7/1)

This regex should be language agnostic (no escape characters used)